# Opencart show upc column content instead of model column content in cart preview

Tags: php, opencart

I am using Opencart v2.2.0 and I am trying to display UPC column instead of model column in shopping cart preview, as well as at final step of checkout. I defined upc variable in controller file and echo it in tpl file of default theme, since the files in question are located there, but still the column stays empty. Also in model file, in query, I switched model for UPC, but still nothing. The problem is, I can't seem to figure out what else should I be doing in order for this to work. I suppose this question sounds too broad, but I am hoping there is someone who can direct me in the right way. Thank you.

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: @Chris thanx for your interest, I figured out what I was missing. I posted the answer bellow. Thanx again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to define UPC in `system/library/cart.php` file. Now it works fine. Maybe it will save somebody else's time.